# Selecting a different record in List View via Script

Tags: filemaker

I have a table in **Filemaker 11** which has fields: `thingID, infoNumber (#), itemHistory`. `infoNumber` displays the order in which we think the item history's happened (sometimes this is incorrect and needs to be rearranged).

> thingID, #, itemHistory
>
> Thing 1, 1, was with Adam
>
> Thing 1, 2, was with Claire
>
> Thing 1, 3, was with Ben
>
> Thing 1, 4, was with Dave

I display these in a **List View** (ordered by infoNumber asc), and a user realises that it actually went "1,3,2,4", I want to have **up and down arrows** visible in order for users to switch them, i.e. clicking on the up arrow on the record with infoNumber=3 will set it to 2 and the old infoNumber=2 will be set as 3.

*How can I write a script to switch these when the user clicks on a button in a list view?*

My idea:

> Set Variable[$clickedDown, infoNumber] #the record we click on's infoNumber
>
> If [ $clickedDown != 1 ]
>
> Set Field [ infoNumber, clickedDown -1 ]
>
> # But how do I move to the record with infoNumber =  clickedDown-1 ??
>
> End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have done this, is to do several Finds, here is my solution for going one way.

> # First you've clicked on something, record its current infoNumber
>
> Set Variable [ $infoNumber, infoNumber ]
>
> # Use -2 (arbitrary) as a temporary place holder
>
> Set Field [ infoNumber = -2]
>
> Error Capture [ On ]
>
> Perform Find [ thingID = $thingID, infoNumber = $infoNumber - 1 ]
>
> If [ Get (LastError = 401) ]
>
> # No results then just re-search temporary and set it back to what it
>   was
>
> Perform Find [ thingID = $thingID, infoNumber = -2 ]
>
> Set Field [ infoNumber, $infoNumber ]
>
> Else
>
> Set Field [ infoNumber, $infoNumber ]
>
> Perform Find [ thingID = $thingID, infoNumber = -2 ]
>
> Set Field [ infoNumber, $infoNumber -1 ]
>
> End If
>
> # Go back to layout you were in before

I would be interested to know if there was a better way!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using relationships. Create a new table occurrence (say, **History Previous**) and link it to the list layout's table occurrence (say, **History**) with the following predicates:

```
History::ThingID = History Previous::ThingID
History::infoNumber > History Previous::infoNumber
```

Sort the relationship by **History Previous::infoNumber**, descending.

This will provide you with a set of related History records that appear earlier in the list for the relevant Thing. The first record will be the immediately previous one, thanks to the sorting.

Now, when you run the script, you can:

```
If [ Count ( History Previous::ThingID ) > 0 ]
Set Variable [ $infoNumber, History Previous::infoNumber ]
Set Field [ History Previous::infoNumber, History::infoNumber ]
Set Field [ History::infoNumber, $infoNumber ]
End If
```

Note that, although the **History Previous** relationship may refer to multiple records, you can rely on the relationship sorting to provide you with access to the first record, both when getting data from it (in the **Set Variable** step) and setting data into it (in the first **Set Field** step).